# About the proof of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis Theorem 1.11

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Theorem 1.11**. Suppose  is an ordered set with the least-upper-bound property, ⊂,  is not empty, and  is bounded below. Let  be the set of all lower bounds of . Then
=sup
exists in , and =inf.

In particular, inf exists in .

**Proof.** Since  is bounded below,  is not empty. Since  consists of exactly those ∈ which satisfy the inequality ≤ for every ∈, we see that every ∈ is an upper bound of . Thus  is bounded above. Our hypothesis about  implies therefore that  has a supremum in ; call it .

If < then (see Definition 1.8)  is not an upper bound of , hence ∉. It follows that ≤ for every ∈. Thus, ∈.

If < then ∉, since  is an upper bound of .

We have shown that ∈ but ∉ if >. In other words,  is a lower bound of , but  is not if >. This means that =inf.

**Here is my question about the theorem.**

When I followed the proof I clearly understood the proof except one thing. That is
"If < then (see Definition 1.8)  is not an upper bound of , hence ∉. It follows that ≤ for every ∈. Thus, ∈.". I can't understand how is it claimed $\alpha\in\text{L}$. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha \leq x$ for every $x\in B$, then by definition of the term "lower bound", $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $B$, hence belongs to the set of lower bounds of $B$, which is $L$.